# Set Camera Size - Parameters vs Intent?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am currently using an intent to take a picture, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

But I really need to set the image size as close to a square as possible.  So after researching it seems you need to do something like this:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

// Once you will see the supported Sizes, you can define them with the method :

setPictureSize(int width, int height);
```

My questions are, do these work together or is it an either/or? Which method works best for my needs?

Again, I have 96px by 96px box for user profile pics.  After user takes the picture I want the image to fill entire box without stretching.  Is the best way to set size at the point of picture being taken, or alter the `imageView` or `bitmap` (or ...?) after the fact?  OR, should I just let the users crop the picture and I can define the cropping area dimensions?

**Edit:  See bounty for updated question.**

Comment: "do these work together or is it an either/or?" -- either/or. The latter is for using the `Camera` yourself to take a picture. The former is to have some other app use the `Camera` itself to take a picture on your behalf.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code allows me to pick image from gallery.  Crop and use my aspect ratio.  I did similar code for using camera.  After user takes picture, it immediately launches an activity to crop the picture.

```
  Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                        Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: use Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"); for camera, and remove photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli  Can you explain what the difference is here?

Comment: If you want to take from camera and not from gallery

Comment: This solution doesn't help me to load crop image directly from camera... any solutions for that? Thanks

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Camera application on Android's emulator crashes with it

Comment: Will the user "when seing what the cameras sees" in preview to taking photo - see the modified aspect ratio. Or see it at as defeault?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Bitmap.createScaleBitmap(Bitmap src, int destWidth, int destHeight, boolean filter)` to resize a bitmap

Comment: Only problem with this, it won't scale the picture correctly?  I think I need to do something like this but let the user crop the picture in a perfect square when they are in the camera app.  Then if I do something like this, I can shrink image?

Comment: You can shrink with code above. But what you really want is cut, is it right?

Comment: Yes, I need cropping.  I actually figured it out... will post final code as answer.  Thanks for the input though on it...  I ended up taking a normal picture with camera, then immediately after, started a new intent to crop it... see answer.

Comment: This will distort the image in case, the scale ratios of the sides are not equal to each other

Answer (score 3):

> Do these work together or is it an either/or? Which method works best for my needs?

No, they do not work together. When you use the camera with an `Intent`, you are asking the system to take a picture for you (i.e. the user gets prompted with the default camera app and takes a picture or chooses one from gallery).

When you use the second approach, you create your own `Camera` object, which is much more customizable than the first one.

With the first method you will have to scale the image afterwards, while with the second, you can take the picture directly in the correct size, so the main difference is that the first is controlled by android, and the second by your app directly, so **the second method works best for your needs.** if you don't want to scale afterwards.

If you're going to scale anyway (read below), then it doesn't matter which approach you use to take the picture, I'd say in that case, **use the default app**.

> Is the best way to set size at the point of picture being taken, or alter the imageView or bitmap (or ...?) after the fact? OR, should I just let the users crop the picture and I can define the cropping area dimensions?

That depends on your needs. In the first case your app alters the picture taken, so **you choose** which portion of the original picture will be the final 96x96 picture. The problem with this method is that you can accidentally crop/strech/manipulate the image in a wrong -or at least, unexpected- manner for the user (i.e. removing part of their face).

When you use the second method, you are providint the user with the **freedom to choose** what part of the picture they want.

If you are able to automatically detect the best portion of the original image, you should go with the first method, but as you are actually asking which is the best method, **you should really go with the second one**, because it provides more **flexibility** to the end user.

Answer (score 2):

*(1) how can it be auto cropped to fit my ImageView (96dp x 96dp),*

It seems like you already have a solution for getting the crop correct. If you want to convert density pixel unit to pixel unit that corresponds to the phone, you need to use the

```
public int dpToPixel(int dp) {
Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

So you can use following as extra

```
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", dpToPixel(96));
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", dpToPixel(96));
```

*(2) How can I shrink the picture in size (make a new bitmap?). These need to be loaded quickly on ListViews. So instead of a 1MB pic being upload, I need one more like 2,000k.*

If you use image that are around the size of 96dp, you don't really need to worry about image sizes. Creating and destroying new bitmaps is usually very dangerous when you try to do multiple of them in an activity. You can easily run into issues such as "Out of Memory" issues. Therefore, it is more advised to use Uri's instead. So, save the uri that you are putting in the intent, and make a list of uris' to display on the listview however you want.

On a imageview, it is setImageURI(Uri uri).

Hope that answers all your questions.