# Android Camera intent through MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT not readable on Mi devices

Tags: android, android-camera

My problem is that I take a picture using camera intent with following code:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

and I have created a file photoFile using the way specified in android documentation from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) for clicking a picture using camera and storing it in specified path

Now, since the file is getting created at the specifed path and nothing is sent to Intent in onActivityResult(). How can I reduce the size of image taken from camera as due to high image resolution it dosen't open on Mi devices and MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT will always return a high resolution image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438085/set-camera-size-parameters-vs-intent

Comment: doesn't help, tried it...Thanks

Comment: reduced the resolution of the image through glide library and the image opens on imageView         Glide.with(context).load(imagePath).override(1280, 720).centerCrop().into(imageView);