# Selecting a specific size image by using an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Code For Select **Multiple Image**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

So my question is how to select **specific** **Height And Width** or **specific** size like **<1MB image** is that posible ? other images disable for selection

Comment: You need to know the path to the image and using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`. See here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#read-bitmap

Comment: @LQGioan that's i know sir how to reduce size of image.. may you need to read my question again

Comment: you need to use `IMG_CONFIG`. Check this https://github.com/alhazmy13/MediaPicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/alhazmy13/mediapickerexample/ImageFragment.java and use that library. if you don't want to use whole library and check its code and use as per your requirement.

Comment: @Ninja thanks for your comment let me check

Answer (score 0):

Will this help ?

```
  Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Let me know , If any problem or issue is there !

Comment: I have used this code earlier for the same use case as you have  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438085/set-camera-size-parameters-vs-intent

Comment: thanks for time sir as i know this code work if we want to crop the image via crop intent .......please read my question again

Comment: The knowledge which i have says , no. You have to read all the images and filter out the images according to your requirement and display with disabled option. I think you are using same use case as Snapchat.

Comment: ohk whats if i want to select multiple image ?